# Does break command in condition of while/until loop on shellscript work on every POSIX environment?

Tags: shell-script, posix

Does POSIX-compliant shell code `while break; do echo x; done` output nothing, without errors on every shell?

Comment: What do you mean by every shell? Not all shells have the same syntax and not all shells are POSIX or even POSIX-like shells.

Comment: NB. the "condition" of a `while` loop can be any number of commands, including `if .. fi`s, `case .. esac`s or other `while` or `for` loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From the [specification of `break`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_15_03):

> the break utility shall exit from the (…) enclosing for, while, or until loop.

> A loop shall enclose a break or continue command if (…) the command is: (…)

> - Contained in a compound-list associated with the loop (either in the compound-list of the loop's do-group or, if the loop is a while or until loop, in the compound-list following the while or until reserved word), and (…)

Putting `break` or `continue` in the condition part of a loop is unusual and may confuse readers, but it's POSIX-compliant.